# How should I merge two dict and not overwrite same keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have two dicts:

```py
d1={'a01': {'prod':1.0}}
d2={'a01': {'dev':2.0}, 'a02': {'dev': 3.0}}
```

I want to merge them into:

```
{
  'a01': {'prod':1.0, 'dev': 2.0},
  'a02': {'dev': 3.0}
}
```

I can do that with a very ugly way, could someone give any suggestion for an ideal method?

This is may sample code, it works but ugly.

```py
def merge_result(r1, r2):
    for id in r2.keys():
        if id in r1.keys():
            r1[id].update(r2[id])
        else:
            r1[id] = dict()
            r1[id].update(r2[id])
    return r1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using basic for loop:

```
d1={'a01': {'prod':1.0}}
d2={'a01': {'dev':2.0}, 'a02': {'dev': 3.0}}

for key,value in d2.items():
    if key in d1.keys():
        d1[key].update(value)
    else:
        d1[key] = value

print (d1)
```

output:

```
{'a01': {'prod': 1.0, 'dev': 2.0}, 'a02': {'dev': 3.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
dic = dict(d1, **d2)
for key in dic.keys():      # find the key in d1
    if key in d1:
        dic[key] = dict(dic[key], **d1[key])
```

output:

```
{'a01': {'dev': 2.0, 'prod': 1.0}, 'a02': {'dev': 3.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
{k: {**d1.get(k,{}), **d2.get(k, {})} for k in {*d1} | {*d2}}
```

output:

```
{'a02': {'dev': 3.0}, 'a01': {'prod': 1.0, 'dev': 2.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in collections module

```
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for x,y in itertools.chain(d1.items() , d2.items()):
    d[x].update(y)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'a01': {'prod': 1.0, 'dev': 2.0}, 'a02': {'dev': 3.0}})
```